# Implementing UIWebView on a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have this `UIWebView` inside a custom `UITableViewCell` that I've created.

The problem is, when I implement the `UIWebView` in `"MyMain"`, it's working but when I scroll the text is readded again and again on over the cells.

When I implement the `UIWebView` in the custom cell class itself it's not showing it at all.

**UITableViewCustomCell.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *wvMainText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *wvTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *wvPrice;
```

**UITableViewCustomCell.m**

```
@synthesize wvMainText = _wvMainText;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I IMPLEMENT THE WEBVIEW?
    }
    return self;
}
```

**MyMain**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myListCell";

    UITableViewCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UITableViewCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (UITableViewCustomCell *)view;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.wvTitle = [[self.arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];
    cell.wvPrice = [[self.arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"price"];

    wv.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"<html><body>%@,%@</body></html>", self.wvTitle, self.wvPrice];

    [wv loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [wv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [wv setOpaque:NO];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...It may solve your issue.
In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method please do changes like this....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myListCell";

UITableViewCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UITableViewCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (UITableViewCustomCell *)view;
        }
    }
       cell.wvTitle = [[self.arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];
    cell.wvPrice = [[self.arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"price"];

    wv.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"<html><body>%@,%@</body></html>", self.wvTitle, self.wvPrice];

    [wv loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [wv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [wv setOpaque:NO];

}


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have placed the webview code inside the if codition..so it will add only once for one cell...It is working or not?

Comment: The problem is, only the visible cells are 0-4, when I scroll down, the first cell that is visible is actually the 5 cell, but he is implemented as indexpath 0, why is that?

Comment: So, the problem with this issue was the dequeue of the cell. when I changed it to: `UITableViewCustomCell *cell = nil;` it worked great!